# Visual Studio Team Services "Link" button is disabled

Tags: azure-devops

I am following instructions to link my account to TFS:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-continuous-integration

It says to go to Team Services accounts, then to choose the account, and click on "Link" but that button is disabled for me. I tried a different account (different credentials, etc.) and I always see the Link button disabled.

Is it a permission issue? What can I do about it?

[Image of disabled Link button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsOyz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not the team services owner, you won't have permission to link azure subscription.

For more possible reasons you can refer:

> Q: Why can't I link my Team Services account?
>
> A: This might happen
>   because:
>
> - You're not the Team Services account owner.
> - You're not at least Co-administrator on the Azure subscription that
>     you want to link.
> - If you don't see any Team Services accounts, your account might
>     already linked to another Azure subscription.
> - If your Team Services account uses Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)
>     to authenticate users, you might have a different directory selected
>     in the Azure portal than the directory that's connected to your Team
>     Services account.
>
>   To select the directory that your Team Services account uses, open the
>     Azure portal's Subscriptions list:
>
>   [image]

More details in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/set-up-billing-for-your-account-vs#qa.

Comment: Thanks! I was in fact not co-admin to any of the accounts I tried to link with. So I created a new one, and was able to link that because I was "owner".